How do I use #each inside a Serilog ExpressionTemplate for writing JSON
I am trying to use a Serilog ExpressionTemplate to write customised Json to a file. I want to output properties from a List parameter, and for this I have written an ExpressionTemplate and inside it trying to use a #each loop to walk the collection of items in the List and output properties from them.
This is what it looks like:
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Debugging;
using Serilog.Templates;

namespace SerilogExpressionTemplateObjectExpansion
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

            using var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "Example")
                .WriteTo.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(
                    "{ {@t: UtcDateTime(@t), @mt, @l: if @l = 'Information' then undefined() else @l, " +
                    " test_results: [" +
                    "    {#each result in @p.test_results}" +
                    "      { name: result.Name, isInStock: {result.IsInStock} }," +
                    "    {#end}" +
                    "  ]" +
                    " @x, ..@p} }\n"))
                .CreateLogger();

            var sut = new SomeListOfItems
            {
                Items = new List<SomeItem>
                {
                    new SomeItem { Name = "Tea", IsInStock = true },
                    new SomeItem { Name = "Coffee", IsInStock = false }
                }
            };
            
            log.ForContext<Program>()
                .Warning("List of results {test_results}", sut.Items);
        }
    }

    internal class SomeItem
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsInStock { get; set; }
    }

    internal class SomeListOfItems
    {
        public List<SomeItem> Items { get; set; } = new List<SomeItem>();
    }
}


But when I try to run it, I get a System.ArgumentException: `Syntax error (line 1, column 103): unexpected ``#```  What am I doing wrong? How can I log sub-properties of a list property?
Help and advice on how to log my list items would be gratefully received.
Note that if I comment out the part of the ExpressionTemplatre that is trying to walk the list, I get output in the ..@p listing that makes sense, but which only lists the object type name for each list item:
                .WriteTo.Console(new ExpressionTemplate(
                    "{ {@t: UtcDateTime(@t), @mt, @l: if @l = 'Information' then undefined() else @l, " +
                    //" test_results: [" +
                    //"    {#each result in @p.test_results}" +
                    //"      { name: result.Name, isInStock: {result.IsInStock} }," +
                    //"    {#end}" +
                    //"  ]" +
                    " @x, ..@p} }\n"))

gives output of:
{"@t":"2024-09-19T14:22:47.0555253Z","@mt":"List of results {test_results}","@l":"Warning","test_results":["SerilogExpressionTemplateObjectExpansion.SomeItem","SerilogExpressionTemplateObjectExpansion.SomeItem"],"SourceContext":"SerilogExpressionTemplateObjectExpansion.Program","Application":"Example"}


Currently, expressions can be nested inside templates, but templates can't be nested inside expressions. The {#if template directive has a corresponding if expression; {#each doesn't - looking into adding this :-)
